# Is there anything like Microsoft's taskkill in Terminal?

Tags: command-line

Is there anything similar to MS Windows' command-line tool [taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491009.aspx) for Ubuntu's command line?

Comment: Command-line's taskkill? What is that?

Comment: @muru In windows you use taskkill in cmd to close the task that you want

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Linux has `killall`. Try `killall firefox`.

But my favorite is command line task manager `htop` - run that, press F5 for process tree view and kill necessary process.

> Well, actually process killing is bad. You have to have pretty good
>   reason to do that. Try to find source of problem.